# Integrating PhoneGap App in Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, unity-game-engine

I need to integrate My PhoneGap App with my unity Game, I tried to integrate Cordova in my project, but it is not working.Please suggest me the steps to integrate PhoneGap App in unity.

I follow the steps mentioned in phoneGap docs. But after adding cordova xcode project in my unity project, when I build the project it is showing the error:

`'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found.
Xcode: Xcode 5.0
Cordova: 3.3.0`

Is there any specific build settings or any other settings so that I can import  CDVViewController.h in my UnityAppController or any other view controller?

Comment: When you say it's not working - why? what errors did you receive ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely deprecated: all systems involved are now totally different.